# Euler 160 : Find the non trivial 5 digits of the factorial

Tags: c, algorithm, math

> Given a number find the 5 digits before the trailing 0. 9! = 362880
>   so f(9)=36288  10! = 3628800 so f(10)=36288  20! = 2432902008176640000
>   so f(20)=17664   Find f(1,000,000,000,000)

For this I have computed the `f(10^6)` and then `f(10^12) =
(f(10^6))^(10^6)`  for computing the `f(n)` ... I am computing the
factorial by removing any 5 and corresponding 2 so that all the
trailing zeros are removed.
But I am getting a wrong answer.
Is there a problem in approach or some silly mistake ?

Code for reference

```
long long po(long long n, long long m, long long mod) {
    if (m == 0) return 1;
    if (m == 1) return n % mod;
    long long r = po(n, m / 2, mod) % mod;
    if (m % 2 == 0) return (r * r) % mod;
    return (((r * r) % mod) * n) % mod;
}

void foo() {
    unsigned long long i, res = 1, m = 1000000 , c = 0, j, res1 = 1, mod;
    mod = ceil(pow(10, 9));
    cout << mod << endl;
    long long a = 0, a2 = 0, a5 = 0;
    for (i = 1 ; i <= m; i++) {
        j = i;
        while (j % 10 == 0)
            j /= 10;
        while (j % 2 == 0) {
            j /= 2;
            a2++;
        }
        while (j % 5 == 0) {
            j /= 5;
            a5++;
        }
        res = (res * j ) % mod;
    }

    a = a2 - a5;

    for (i = 1; i <= a; i++)
        res = (res * 2) % mod;
    for (i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        res1 = (res1 * res) % mod;
    }
    cout << res1 << endl;
}
```

Comment: also, isn't project euler something you should solve yourself rather than asking for help... just saying if you let someone else solve it for you, not only will you get nothing out of it but also the answer will now be on SO for everyone to see.

Answer (score 6):

Your equality `f(10^12) = (f(10^6))^(10^6)` is wrong.  f() is based on factorials, not powers.

Comment: My assumption : we have computed the last 5 digits of (10^6)! now all the other digits > 10^6 will have the same 5 trailing digits using which we have computed the (10^6) !

So f(2*(10^6) ) = f(10^6)! * f(10^6)
In similar fashion 
f(n*10^6) = (f(10^6))^n

Comment: @titan: but the trailing zeros in the numbers mean you can't treat the whole problem module 1000000 like that.  For example, 123000 in your first million will contribute different digits to the 5 than 1123000 will, so they aren't equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are erroneous:

- **f(10^12)** is not the same as **f(10^6)^(10^6)**.
- in order to get the low order non 0 digits of the factorial, it does not suffice to remove all multiples of `10`, `2` and `5` from the multiplicands. Removing the multiples of `10` is a good idea, for `5` and `2`, you should remove the factor 2 or 5 only if the other multiplicand is a multiple of 5 and 2 respectively.

You should simplify the code and compute modulo some power of 10, but 10^9 seems too high as **10^9 * 10^12** will overflow 64-bit type `unsigned long long`.